# Replace Recyclerview's textview item to imageview item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView`with `TextView` items and want to replace the last item to `ImageView`. The numbers must be text, that's why I can't make all them `ImageView`
It mmust be like this: 
[image]

I add `TextView` and `ImageView` to recycler row item and make the visibility of ImageView `gone`. Here is my `ViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestView, position: Int) {

        holder.testName?.text = listOfTests?.get(position)?.testName
        holder.txtNumberIcon?.text = listOfTests?.get(position)?.txtNumberIcon

        if (listOfTests?.get(listOfTests!!.size.minus(1))?.txtNumberIcon == dont know what condition must be here) {


            holder.txtNumberIcon?.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.imageStarIcon?.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            Glide
                .with(context?.applicationContext!!)
                .load(listOfTests?.get(listOfTests!!.size.minus(1))?.testNumberIcon)
                .into(holder.imageStarIcon!!)

        }
```

What condition I must write to replace last item from textview to imageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand it right. 
If the `listOfTests` has 10 elements you want 9 cells from the `RecyclerView` to be `TextView's` and 1 `ImageView`.

If so:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestView, position: Int) {

    holder.testName?.text = listOfTests?.get(position)?.testName
    holder.txtNumberIcon?.text = listOfTests?.get(position)?.txtNumberIcon

    if (position == listOfTests.size - 1) { /* position starts from 0 */
        // I would suggest to load the image only for the element that will be displayed
        Glide.with(context?.applicationContext!!)
              .load(listOfTests?.get(position)?.testNumberIcon)
              .into(holder.imageStarIcon!!)
        holder.txtNumberIcon?.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.imageStarIcon?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else {
        holder.txtNumberIcon?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.imageStarIcon?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```